# GCP Terraform attach policy to a role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

does anyone know how to attach policy to role in terraform in GCP? On AWS I could make multiple policies in terraform, then bind them to a role - that way when I added/removed policies the roles stayed without deletion - I don't see anything like it on GCP provider for terraform.

Also the GCP one seems a bit skinny -

Can I even declare new IAM member in terraform ? the only reference I see is some side note reference to `google_project_iam_member` without any docs or explanation
`

Answer (score 1):

The [GCP IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) works on a way for `who` is doing `what` to `which` resources.
This

- `who` is the member like user, group, service account and so on
- `what` is the [role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)
- `Which` is the resources (some roles can be be assign on individual resource/project even in folder or organization)

[`Role`s](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) are the accumulation of permissions and can be three types 1.  [Primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles) 2. [Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles) and 3. [Custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#custom_roles)

In GCP A Policy is a collection of bindings[3]. Each binding tied  [member](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#concepts_related_identity) with [role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) and [condition](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview).

Now in terraform the [IAM policy for projects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html#google_project_iam_policy-1) can be defined also particular [binding](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html#google_project_iam_binding-1) can be made. Also customer roles can be created with [this example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam_custom_role.html)

I hope the linked documents can help you to get some understanding on GCP IAM and help you deploy according to your use case.

Comment: I understand the policies and the types of roles but I would like to know if you can have a defined role in terraform (you can) and if you can dynamically assign and release new permissions from it without its deletion

Comment: If I am not mistaken your are trying to achieve [Editing an existing custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#editing_an_existing_custom_role) task, but from terraform. am I correct?

Comment: I'm going for exactly that

Comment: then I think [google_project_iam_custom_role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam_custom_role.html) and after creating the role if you modify your configuration and re-apply it should change your existing configuration